# Feedback/bug tracking system for an alpha/beta phase website?

Tags: web-development, issue-trackers

I'm developing a website and it's closing onto a private alpha/beta phase. It will be exposed to a small selected group of individuals who will provide a fair amount of feedback.

What options do I have for this feedback system? I would certainly like to make it collaborative (excluding email). I could mock up a really simple message board, but would rather use my time elsewhere.

The feedback will mainly consist of feature suggestions and bug reports.

Edit: Actually, would prefer if it's a free hosted service.

Comment: Made CW as per: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/212/list-of-x-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) or [Roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/) (i prefer Roundup). So your users can reports bugs, open feature requests and many more.

Maybe a Google search for "issue tracker" or "bug tracker" can give you a overview of the different available tools.

Comment: I decided to host locally and go with Trac using a one-click-install Bitnami stack (WAMP) http://bitnami.org/stack/trac.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/). It is not as extensive as BugZilla, but most users find it easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) is a very good issue tracker and perfect for this job (we use it extensively and it greatly improved how we deal with bugs and feature requests). Jira is offered either as a hosted solution or you can maintain your own install (what we do). It is however not free.

Answer (score 0):

[Lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/) it's very good, you can try it for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Trac and are looking for a free hosted service check out http://www.projectlocker.com

Answer (score 0):

Joel Spolsky, the owner of this site, offers a free/trial hosted version of his FogBugz bug tracking software. It would be worth at least evaluating I think, especially since it's hosted & thus there is not a whole lot of work involved setting it up.